# Likewise: joined Active Directory but cannot write shares

Tags: 10.10, active-directory, likewise

I have never used a Linux system in an AD environment before and am trying to join my laptop running Ubuntu to join our Active Directory (DC is a Windows Server 2008 machine) using Likewise-open.

- Using the GUI wizard, I have joined the domain.
- I can mount network shares using CIFS

My `fstab` entry looks like this:

```
//server/share  /mnt/foo    cifs    auto,iocharset=utf8,rw,credentials=/home/aron/.smbcredentials   0   0
```

**Problem:**
 I only have read access to our fileserver. What more is needed to get the AD to recognize me as a user who has the appropriate rights?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem.

It turned out, this would not work without a valid GID or UID parameter in fstab.

I added my UID to the fstab entry and I can now write the share perfectly.

[This resource](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) has helped me come to this conclusion.